# Use decorator to mock an import within the wrapped function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, moto

I want to write a decorator that, when applied, mocks an import for the mocked function, e.g., I want the following code:

```py
from .decorator import mock_api
from .biz_logic import call_api


@mock_api
def test_api_mock():
    call_api()
```

Where `call_api` is contained in a module that either directly or indirectly imports a class called `Api` from the module `api_library`. I want the implementation to look something like this, but it doesn't work

```py
import mock


class MockApi:
    pass


def mock_api(func):
    @mock.patch(
        "api_library.Api", mock.MagicMock(return_value=MockApi)
    )
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

I'm inspired by the `moto` library, and want to accomplish something similiar to what they've done with
convenient decorators like `mock_s3`

Comment: The mock is related to some method/class that is in module you wanted to mock. If you import the `api_library.Api` in **some_module.py** and are testing the **some_module** methods and classes, you have to `mock some_module.API`.

Comment: I know there's a way to do it with a decorator without explicitly mocking the import within every module that imports it, because `moto` does it here https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/moto/core/models.py#L508

I'm trying to read through their code but there's quit a bit of abstraction, and I can't quite tell how they're doing it

Comment: Follow the white rabbit. Take a look at method definition of `fake_boto3_client` [here](https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/9b3e9328227c795bfe5896a89b19cd4989407b14/moto/core/models.py#L465).